# Keeping leading zeros with find and replace

Tags: excel, replace, leading-zero

I'm using Excels find and replace to remove hyphens from long numbers. They are mixed between birth dates and organisation numbers that have been filled with leading zeros to have the same number of characters. There are a LOT of numbers so find and replace seems to be the simplest solution to remove the hyphens. 
But when i use find and replace the leading zeros are truncated and I have not found a solution to keep them afterwards.

For example i have:

```
19551230-1234
01234567-8901
```

and after find and replace I have

```
1,95512E+11
12345678901
```

but want the format as:

```
195512301234
012345678901
```

So I want to keep the leading zeros after find and replace. I've tried formatting the cells as text, but it doesn't work as the find and replace automatically truncates the leading zero and keeps the remaining characters, so the zero is completely removed. I am using Excel 2010, but answers for several versions are appreciated.

Comment: Format the cells as text before doing the find replace.

Comment: I did that already, and it doesn't work.

Comment: are the numbers always 12 digits?

Comment: You could just use `SUBSTITUTE()`, no? `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","")`

Comment: Always 12 digits, and the substitution solution worked. Thanks.

Comment: You could also format the cells: `000000000000` and it will do what you want.

Comment: Dang it @BruceWayne, Why do we fall down?

Answer (score 2):

Just put a single quote in front of your leading number - ex. '01234 It will take the number as-is literally and the quote will not show in the field.

Comment: Additionally if you are trying to do a VLOOKUP or some other function referencing that number with the quote and can't match it because of that single quote, you can do a "Text to Column" removing the single quote (') and setting the field type to Text and it will not remove the leading zero.

Answer (score 1):

Use the SUBSTITUTE formula instead of Find and Replace like so:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),"/",""),")",""),"(",""),"-","")
```

The result is text.