# Excel - Find-and-Replace with Leading Zero

Tags: excel

Can't find any information about this online for some reason. Say you have an Excel sheet, and in cell A1 you put the number 5. Now, you want to replace all 5's in your document with "0001". It can be stored as text, as a number, anything - it just needs to contain "0001".

If you go to Find and Replace, in "Find what:", you put "5". In "Replace with:", you put "0001". When you hit "Replace All", cell A1 will contain "1", not "0001". How do I get it to contain "0001"?

Note that the obvious answers don't work well. If beforehand I change cell A1 to the "Text" type, I'm able to type in 0001 and it will stick - however, if I use Find and Replace to put in 0001, it removes all leading zeros anyway.

An answer here: [Keeping leading zeros with find and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43739663/keeping-leading-zeros-with-find-and-replace) seems to suggest putting in a formula - that's not what I'm looking for. I want the cell to contain "0001" as if I had just typed it in, in a text cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just be able to format the cell, custom format `0000`.

[image]

(I accidentally did `00000` in the .gif, but you'd just want four zeros, `0000`)

Comment: until you added the video, I as going to say that was kind of brief answer

Comment: so if a picture is worth a thousand words.  How many words is your video answer worth?

Comment: @ForwardEd - How would I expand without the `.gif`? I know we tend to dislike one liner answers, but it seems straightforward.  Would/should I just add more info on the Custom Formatting option?

Comment: This was what worked for me! No formulas or changing the text to anything else. For my purpose, I actually went a slightly different route - I went to the Find and Replace dialog with the Options open, and changed the "Replace with:" formatting the same way you did. That way all the cells I wanted had that formatting, and none of the cells I didn't want.

Comment: The only problem with this answer is that all cells that contain `5` in the sheet would need to be formatted this way. Still, +1

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 yeah I ran into that, see my comment just above yours - you can change the formatting via Find and Replace as well, so you don't have to do it beforehand

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

Try to find "`5`" and replace with "`= TEXT(1,"0000")`" or equivalently, "`= "0001"`"

Comment: Haha OP definitely said they aren't looking for a formula ;)

Comment: @CallumDA LOL!!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a single quote in front, it will keep the zeroes. ('0001)

Comment: That's true, but I don't want the quote - I just want 0001. If you set the cell type to "text", you can type 0001 and it will keep it just fine, without the single quote. The issue is that Find and Replace doesn't seem to respect the "text" cell type

Comment: I'm so used to Excel changing leading zeroes on me that using a single quote is my default. It doesn't seem to cause any issues with calculations, macros or formulas.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using for some external programs to read in, and the apostrophe caused problems

Answer (score -1):

Stick a `'` in front of the `0001` in the `REPLACE` function.

i.e. - `'0001`

Then, if you want to delete the leading apostrophe from column. Select the column, click the green box at the top left corner of the cell. Click convert to number. All of the cells selected should now be formatted as a number without the quote.

Comment: Thats not the case. The poster did not want to have the leading apostrophe! Ive showed the complete process for what the poster is actually after. Not just half the answer!